# Mapping of a row of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe named df.

| id | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x,y |
| 2 | z |
| 3 | a |

The mapping condition is {'x' : 1, 'z' : 2, 'ELSE' : 0}

my desired output dataframe should look like,

| id | letter | map |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x,y | 1 |
| 2 | z | 2 |
| 2 | a | 0 |

Which means, even any of the letters in column `letter` is x, then the column `map` should be 1.

Without iterating through each row of the dataframe, is there any way to do that?

Comment: what if you have `'x,z'`?

Comment: Assume that x and z cannot be together

Comment: if xb(not x, b) exist in letter, map 1 or 0? if 1 use my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

##### pure pandas

```
cond = {'x' : 1, 'z' : 2, 'ELSE' : 0}

df['map'] = (df['letter']
 .str.split(',').explode()
 .map(lambda x: cond.get(x, cond['ELSE']))
 .groupby(level=0).max()
)
```

In case of multiple values I would get the max.

Alternative for the first valid match:

```
df['map'] = (df['letter']
 .str.split(',').explode()
 .map(cond)
 .groupby(level=0).first()
 .fillna(cond['ELSE'], downcast='infer')
)
```

##### list comprehension

Or using a list comprehension, here the first valid match would be used:

```
cond = {'x' : 1, 'z' : 2, 'ELSE' : 0}

df['map'] = [next((cond[x] for x in s.split(',') if x in cond),
                  cond['ELSE'])  for s in df['letter']]
```

```
   id letter  map
0   1    x,y    1
1   2      z    2
2   3      a    0
```

Answer (score 1):

use `np.select`

```
import numpy as np

cond1 = df['letter'].str.contains('x')
cond2 = df['letter'].str.contains('z')
df.assign(map=np.select([cond1, cond2], [1, 2], 0))
```

output:

```
    id  letter  map
0   1   x,y     1
1   2   z       2
2   3   a       0
```